# Granting permission to a stored procedure (not a user) to run a SQL Server trace

Tags: sql-server, trace

I need to allow a limited number of users to run a very explicit set of traces on a production server with windows authentication only where the owner of the procedure has ALTER TRACE but the intended developers do not. I created a stored procedure with EXECUTE AS OWNER that sets the fields, filters and schedule needed to run the trace, imports results to a table and returns the results set. I must avoid giving users ALTER TRACE but haven’t been able to get over this hump. I hope to avoid using a SQL agent task but have run out of ideas.

Comment: You need to use [module signig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/signing-stored-procedures-in-sql-server)